# How do nameserver domains get resolved?

Tags: dns, nameservers, infrastructure

Do further understand the DNS I did a `dig +trace google.de @8.8.8.8` and captured the packets via wireshark.

As you can see in this screenshot nic.de lists all DNS servers (ns1.google.com, ns2.google.com...)[image: Wireshark screenshot]

The trace commands then continue and ask ns3.google.com after the "A" record of google.de.
Here comes the part I don't understand. It just directly connects to 2001:4860:4802:36::a (what seems to be ns3.google.com). How does it know that this is the address of ns3.google.com it is nowhere in the packets I even did a string search on all packets but it could not find anything.
[image: Second Wireshark Screenshot]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/482913/is-dig-trace-always-accurate